# Java compilation failed for generics

Tags: java, generics

```
public <T> void saveData(String key, T value) {

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor =  sharedPreferences.edit();

        if (value instanceof String) {
            editor.putString(key, (String) value);
        } else if (value instanceof Boolean) {
            editor.putBoolean(key, (boolean) value);
        } else if (value instanceof Integer) {
            editor.putInt(key, (int) value);
        } else if (value instanceof Float) {
            editor.putFloat(key, (float) value);
        } else if (value instanceof Long) {
            editor.putLong(key, (long) value);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Unknown type");
        }

        editor.apply();
    }
```

When I am building the project then I am getting error as

```
error: incompatible types: T cannot be converted to boolean
where T is a type-variable:
T extends Object declared in method <T>saveData(String,T)
```

This error is coming for long, int and float as well.

Comment: Why are you using generics for this and in this way? Looks like a possible [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) to me.

Comment: Is there any issue in using it?

Comment: You are using generics but to no purpose or benefit. It makes no sense.

Comment: Just use Object instead of T and change the type to void only.

Comment: That said, you're confusing the primitive type boolean with the wrapper type Boolean. An object can be a Boolean, but it can't be a boolean.

Comment: While using a wrapper might appease the compiler, it doesn't make this code good or useful in a generic sense.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I will keep this in mind

Answer (score -1):

The error is only for primitive types, so pay attention on using primiteves instead of Objects.  Generics work with objects.

Another way to achieve this with no `if` at all, so `cyclomatic complexity` 0:

```
blic void caller(){
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    saveDate(editor, "key-string", "string value");
    saveDate(editor, "key-boolean", true);
    saveDate(editor, "key-integer", 7);
    saveDate(editor, "key-float", 7.0f);
    saveDate(editor, "key-long", 7L);
    editor.apply();
}


public void saveData(Editor editor, String key, String value) {
    editor.putString(key, (String) value);
}

public void saveData(Editor editor, String key, Boolean value) {
    editor.putBoolean(key, (boolean) value);
}

public void saveData(Editor editor, String key, Integer value) {
    editor.putInt(key, (int) value);
}
public void saveData(Editor editor, String key, Float value) {
    editor.putFloat(key, (float) value);
}
public void saveData(Editor editor, String key, Long value) {
    editor.putLong(key, (long) value);
}
```

This way you pay the penalty in number of rows which is higher.

Comment: What's the point of using the wrapper types in this case? Also, there is absolutely no point in having these thin wrapper methods around the editor.put* methods in the first place.

Comment: so for you brings 0 benefit having 5 different methods, one for each type? you would prefer a single method switching the cases based on the `if instanceof` condition? I understand your downvote, but anyway mine was **another way** as mentioned in the answer... I think you didn't even read well the question because I didn't introduce any wrapper.

Comment: The benefit is (almost) 0 because there is already the same set of 5 methods in the Editor class - almost because you get the benefit of all having the same name. Still, this doesn't answer the actual question.

Comment: My point is to not use generics. But I see your point, you don't even need the methods, one can simple call the target method directly. This answer anyway solves the compilation issues the question is asking.(perhaps is not the best way)